# Installing SQL Server command-line tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, mssql

I am following this documentation: [Install the SQL Server command-line tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017#tools) 
and I am getting this:

```
(base) khalid@Khalid:~$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for khalid: 

OK
(base) khalid@Khalid:~$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial main
(base) khalid@Khalid:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]          
Get:4 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017 xenial InRelease 
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease              
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:11 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                          
Hit:14 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease         
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (149 kB/s)                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
(base) khalid@Khalid:~$ sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Why 16.04?

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

It should be 18.04:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

For all available listing, check: https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/